# Histogram in R adding labels and colors to 2 hist plots

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have 2 datasets and I run the hist command in R in order to create the histogram charts. I combined them in one plot at the end. So my code is like this:

```
hist(dist_x1,col="green",pch=20,cex=4,breaks=15)
hist(dist_x2,col="red",pch=20,cex=4,breaks=15,add=TRUE)
box()
```

I want to put 2 labels in the hist plot created, (something like the legend in R) to indicate what is what and differentiate these 2 histograms existed in the same plot.

any ideas?

Comment: Does the answer work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked perfected.I forgot a parameter in legend...I am now trying to do the curve of normalization appear in the hist plot...

Comment: So mark it correct please :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a legend

```
dist_x1 <- rnorm(1000)
dist_x2 <- rnorm(500)
hist(dist_x1,col="green",pch=20,cex=4,breaks=15)
hist(dist_x2,col="red",pch=20,cex=4,breaks=15,add=TRUE)
legend("topright", c("dist_x1", "dist_x2"), fill=c("red", "green"))
box()
```

yields:

[image]